# AWS remove public / private key

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I have access to my private key and I can use it for SSH, But for development purposes I want to be able to just use the regular SSH method by connecting via the IP and doing it without having to have the key.

Connect to IP -> Type username, Password -> Logged in

Comment: You can do that if you want. Do you have a question about it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton  
Sorry, I didn't word it properly :D How do I go about doing it? When I tried to SSH via the IP without the key it would not allow me to as it was expecting a private / public key

Comment: Password authentication is off by default. You'd have to turn it on... but you shouldn't.

Comment: @ceejayoz For development purposes I do not want to have the authentication method that's added at the minute, How do I go about enabling password authentication?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=enabling+password+authentication+AWS